# why rabbitmq message consumption is so slow

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue

Currently I am making logic to consume Message using Rabbitmq. However, contrary to expectations, it takes too long to consume the message.

If you look at the Queued messages graph in the picture above, you can see Unacked and Ready stacking up.
Looking at the message rates below, the publish speed is fast, but the consumer ack speed is too slow.

I'm not sure if the Rabbitmq Configuration I've developed is wrong or if I forgot to set the listener configuration.
The rabbitmq message I receive is a callback message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.[image]

[image]
**This is Rabbitmq configuration and RabbitListener configuration**

```
@Configuration
@Profile({ProfileConfig.RABBITMQ})
public class RabbitmqConfig {

  @Value("${rabbitmq.queue.name}")
  private String queueName;

  @Value("${rabbitmq.exchange.name}")
  private String exchangeName;

  @Value("${rabbitmq.routing.key.callback}")
  private String routingKey;

  @Value("${rabbitmq.fetch-count}")
  private Integer fetchCount;

  @Bean
  Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(queueName, true);
  }

  @Bean
  DirectExchange directExchange() {
    return new DirectExchange(exchangeName);
  }

  @Bean
  Binding binding(DirectExchange directExchange, Queue queue) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(directExchange).with(routingKey);
  }

  @Bean
  public RabbitListenerContainerFactory<SimpleMessageListenerContainer> prefetchOneContainerFactory(
      SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ConnectionFactory factory)
  {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleFactory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(simpleFactory, factory);
    simpleFactory.setPrefetchCount(fetchCount);

    return simpleFactory;
  }

}


@RabbitListener(queues = {"${rabbitmq.queue.name}"}, concurrency = "3", containerFactory = "prefetchOneContainerFactory")
  public void receiveMessage(final String message, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) {
    try {
      JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
      JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(message);
      String messageType = json.get("messageType").toString();
      log.debug("Receive Queue  Key={}, Message = {}", messageType, message);
      AsyncType asyncType = AsyncType.valueOf(messageType);
      executeMessage(asyncType, message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      traceService.removeTraceId();
      traceService.printErrorLog(log, "Fail to deal receive message.", e, PrintStackPolicy.ALL);
    } finally {
        try {
          channel.basicAck(tag, false);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
          traceService.printErrorLog(log, "Fail to send ack to RabbitMQ", e, PrintStackPolicy.ALL);
        }
    }
  }
```

The goal is to consume messages to Rabbitmq faster.

However, the current consumption speed is too slow.

Comment: did you add some logs every line in receiveMessage function?

Comment: no not every line, I received the callback message and put logs at the beginning and end of the message processing part.                                     
    log.info("[{}] Get Asset Created Callback Message. - start {}", traceId, message);                                                                                                       
    log.info("[{}] Get Asset Created Callback Message. - finish {}", traceId, message);

Comment: When I do the jmeter load test, it takes a very long time to consume the message.

Comment: Looking at the message rate graph, the publish speed is fast, but the consumer ack speed does not exceed 7/s. If anyone knows, please help.

Comment: From the screen capture, it seems you have multiple consumers, but have set the prefetch count to 100.
This would typically translate to a single consumer processing large batches of messages (would receive up to a 100 messages in one go), while the other have nothing to do.
So if higher consumption is intended to occur through multiple consumers working in parallel, consider reducing the prefetch.

Comment: Thank you for posting your reply. But changing preFetchCount doesn't solve it. After all, message processing speed is similar under the same load. Between about 6 and 10 tps.